# Why can't navigate java code in emacs using cscope

Tags: emacs, elisp, cscope

I installed cscope 15.7a, and my .emacs setting like:

```
;;cscope
(require 'xcscope)
(add-hook 'java-mode-common-hook '(lambda()(require 'xcscope)))
```

I can use `cscope` when opening C/C++ code files; and there is a `cscope` menu above the emacs menu bar,  while it don't have when opening java code, so that I can't use cscope to navigate java codes in emacs.

what should I do to use cscope navigating java codes in emacs?

Maybe it's a silly question, sorry for this. I hope someone can help.

Comment: add `(add-hook 'java-mode-hook (function cscope:hook))` in xcscope.el, it works for me. and I can use cscope in java mode.

Comment: why does nobody not interest in this question?

Answer (score 0):

3 steps to use cscope for java in emacs:

1. find . -name "*.java" > cscope.files
2. add java in cscope-indexer file
   ie change  |cc|hh)$     to   |cc|hh|java)$
3. add a hook as gladman mentioned:
   (add-hook 'java-mode-hook (function cscope:hook))

Answer (score 0):

For emacs 25 and xcscope 1.3, you can add a hook in the .emacs file or .emacs.d/init.el like this:

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook (function cscope-minor-mode))